# Call a different string method based on a flag in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to be able to call a different String method based on what is passed in a parameter. For example, my parameter is "%XYZ%". If there are percent signs on both sides of XYZ, further down in code I want to say `SomeString.Contains("XYZ").`

If there is a percent sign only on the left of XYZ, further down in code I want to say

```
SomeString.EndsWith("XYZ").
```

Ideally, I want something like this:

```
   With objSearchTerms             
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(.ProjectName) Then                       
     If .ProjectName.StartsWith("%") AndAlso .ProjectName.EndsWith("%") Then                           
         'MyStringMethod = Contains
     ElseIf .ProjectName.EndsWith("%") Then
         'MyStringMethod = StartsWith
     ElseIf .ProjectName.StartsWith("%") Then
         'MyStringMethod = EndsWith
     Else
         'MyStringMethod = Equals
     End If
    End If
   End With
```

Then further down I want to be able to say:

```
 filingList = filingRepository.GetList (Function(e) e.SERFFTrackingToFilings.Any(Function(x) x.SERFFTracking.Number.*MyStringMethod*(objTerms.TrackingNumber))
```

Thank you.

Comment: So your question is what?

Comment: A variable that stores a function is a delegate object reference.  Use the `AddHandler` statement to assign it.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a reference to the string that you want to run the method on, then you could assign the method to a `Func<T, TResult>` delegate, and invoke the delegate, something like.

```
Dim MyStringMethod As Func(Of String, Boolean)
'...
MyStringMethod = AddressOf(SomeString.Contains)
'...
Dim result As Boolean = MyStringMethod(SomeOtherString)    'SomeString.Contains(SomeOtherString)
```

But it looks like your `SomeString` is in an anonymous function where you may not already have a reference to it. Possible workaround:

```
Dim MyStringMethod As Func(Of String, String, Boolean)
'...if...
MyStringMethod = Function(a As String, b As String) a.Contains(b)
'...else if...
MyStringMethod = Function(a As String, b As String) a.StartsWith(b)
'...etc.
 filingList = filingRepository.GetList (Function(e) e.SERFFTrackingToFilings.Any(Function(x) MyStringMethod(x.SERFFTracking.Number, objTerms.TrackingNumber)))
```

Comment: I think I ended up doing something similar to your answer. At least I was thinking along the same lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following:

I created a Module:

```
 Module StringExtensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function ProcessString(ByVal strToCheck As String, ByVal strOperand As String, ByVal strWhatTocheck As String) As Boolean
        Select Case strOperand
            Case "Contains"
                Return strToCheck.Trim.ToUpper.Contains(strWhatTocheck.Trim.ToUpper)
            Case "StartsWith"
                Return strToCheck.Trim.ToUpper.StartsWith(strWhatTocheck.Trim.ToUpper)
            Case "EndsWith"
                Return strToCheck.Trim.ToUpper.Contains(strWhatTocheck.Trim.ToUpper)
            Case "Equals"
                Return strToCheck.Trim.ToUpper.Equals(strWhatTocheck.Trim.ToUpper)
            Case Else
                Throw New ApplicationException("Can't match ProcessString(). ")
        End Select
    End Function

End Module
```

Then in the calling method I used the module like this:

```
       Dim filingListDTO As New List(Of DTO.FilingDetailsViewModel)
       Dim strNumberOperand As String = ""
       Dim strProjectNumber As String = ""   

  With model
     If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(.ProjectNumber) Then
                If .ProjectNumber.StartsWith("%") AndAlso .ProjectNumber.EndsWith("%") Then
                    strNumberOperand = "Contains"
                ElseIf .ProjectNumber.EndsWith("%") Then
                    strNumberOperand = "StartsWith"
                ElseIf .ProjectNumber.StartsWith("%") Then
                    strNumberOperand = "EndsWith"
                Else
                    strNumberOperand = "Equals"
                End If
                strProjectNumber = .ProjectNumber.Replace("%", "").Trim.ToUpper
                .ProjectNumber = strProjectNumber
            End If
   End With

       filingListDTO = (From f In <<someList>>
                             Where f.ProjectNumber.ProcessString(strNumberOperand, strProjectNumber) _
                             Select f).ToList
```